# Best index for this scenario

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, index

There is a table in our database

```
tblCustomText(
  ParentID int NOT NULL,
  CustomFieldID int NOT NULL,
  Value char(50) NOT NULL, 
  Log_CreateDate datetime NOT NULL
)
```

(ParentID+CustomFieldID) is unique.

Read operations are like: SELECT Value WHERE ParenID=@p1 AND CustomFieldID = @p2 (sometimes instead of WHERE, JOIN is used)

Write operations: 85% is INSERT, 13% is UPDATE, 2% DELETE. (By ParentID+CustomFieldID)

Now, I'd like to know what indexes should be defined for this table? (It contains ~6M rows)

Comment: I do question `char(50)` for the value column. Are these values always going to be exactly 50 characters? If not, I strongly recommend `varchar` and verifying that 50 is the right upper limit. I'd also verify that you will never need to support Unicode in this column - I would probably use `nvarchar` to be safe. On 2008 R2 and up, data compression will help you negate the extra costs of storing non-Unicode data in `nvarchar` columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like the following would be sufficient:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblCustomText
(
  ParentID int NOT NULL,
  CustomFieldID int NOT NULL,
  Value char(50) NOT NULL, 
  Log_CreateDate datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ParentID, CustomFieldID)
);
```

You may also find later that you are querying by date, so you may want a non-clustered index on the `Log_CreatedDate` column.

Comment: +1 for the inclusion of the DATETIME field in a nonclustered index, and having a more complete answer than mine.

Comment: How about making an (extra) index for (ParentID, CustomFieldID,Value). Does it make sense? (It certainly improves read speed).

Comment: @jaraics What query would that satisfy better? You know that the clustered index includes both Value and Log_CreateDate, right?

Answer (score 0):

Since ParentID + CustomFieldID are unique AND NOT NULL, I would suggest you make a clustered primary key on the combination of those two fields.